# CC2530: adapting AVR/pgmspace.h for Zigbee

Tags: avr, c, embedded, ethernet, 8051

Goal: Adapt ENC28J60 codes written for ATMega328p (http://tuxgraphics.org/electronics/201204/embedded-ethernet-client.shtml) for CC2530.

Problem: No equivalent library for [AVR/pgmspace.h](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html#ga75acaba9e781937468d0911423bc0c35) available for easy transition.

Need to make equivalents for:

1. prog_char
2. uint8_t
3. *progmem_s
4. pgm_read_byte()
5. PROGMEM

Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The 8051 compilers support `code` memory directly.

Comment: @TurboJ so should I #define them as simple variables. For eg. prog_char = char. Using IAR embedded workbench for 8051 btw